# parse input to rational in Julia

Tags: input, type-conversion, julia, rational-number

I want to read the user input and store it as a Rational, whatever the type: integer, float ot rational. For instance:

```
5 --> store it as 5//1
2.3 --> store it as 23//10
4//7 --> store it as 4//7
```

At the moment I wrote the following:

```
a = convert(Rational,parse(Float64,readline(STDIN)))
```

which is fine if I input an integer, like 5.

But if I input 2.3, `a` stores `2589569785738035//1125899906842624`
.

And if I input a fraction (whether in the form `4/7` or the form `4//7`) I get an `ArgumentError: invalid number format for Float64`.

How to solve the Float&Rational problems?

Comment: This *should* be available by ``parse(Rational{Int},string)``, but currently this is not implemented.

Comment: @mschauer Yeah, I tried but didn't work. Will it be so in 0.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to [parse](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.parse) the raw input to an `Expr` (symbols), [eval](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.MainInclude.eval) the expression, convert it to a `Float64` and use [rationalize](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.rationalize) to simplify the rational generated:

```
julia> rationalize(convert(Float64, eval(parse("5"))))
5//1

julia> rationalize(convert(Float64, eval(parse("2.3"))))
23//10

julia> rationalize(convert(Float64, eval(parse("4/7"))))
4//7

julia> rationalize(convert(Float64, eval(parse("4//7"))))
4//7
```

`rationalize` works with approximate floating point number and you could specify the error in the parameter [`tol`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.rationalize).

<sub>tested with Julia Version 0.4.3</sub>

---

***Update***: The `parse` method was deprecated in Julia version >= 1.0. There are two methods that should be used: [`Base.parse`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.parse) (just for numbers, and it requires a *Type* argument) and [`Meta.parse`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Meta.parse-Tuple%7BAbstractString%7D) (for expressions):

```
julia> rationalize(convert(Float64, eval(parse(Int64, "5"))))
5//1

julia> rationalize(convert(Float64, eval(parse(Float64, "2.3"))))
23//10
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication (then division) by a highly composite integer works pretty well.

```
julia> N = 2*2 * 3*3 * 5*5 * 7 * 11 * 13
900900

julia> a = round(Int, N * parse(Float64, "2.3")) // N
23//10

julia> a = round(Int, N * parse(Float64, "5")) // N
5//1

julia> a = round(Int, N * parse(Float64, "9.1111111111")) // N
82//9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own `parse`:

```
function Base.parse(::Type{Rational{Int}}, x::ASCIIString)
    ms, ns = split(x, '/', keep=false)
    m = parse(Int, ms)
    n = parse(Int, ns)
    return m//n
end

Base.parse(::Type{Rational}, x::ASCIIString) = parse(Rational{Int}, x)
```